# WCF Service not restfull

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2013

My first WEB servicee usinf Visual Studio 2013 Express WEB, and I can't make it restfull. basically want to return a json string and got the following service definition;

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Name")]
        string Name();
```

Implementation of Name just returns a string which is shown when I Invoke the function through the WCF Test Client, but calling the http://localhost:58116/Service1.svc/Name returns nothing. I was expecting a json representation of the Name.

Any idea's?

Comment: what version of framework you are using? Can you post web.config file?

Comment: If OP is using 2013, good bet they're on 4.5.1.  Web.config file will definitely help in troubleshooting.

Comment: <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>

Comment: Tried in IE as well, received
This error (HTTP 400 Bad Request) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the web server, but the webpage could not be found because of a problem with the address.

Looks like the /Name uri is not accepted (IIS Express)

Comment: http://localhost:58116/Service1.svc returns a good page